# Hash Function that is Collision Resistant but not Puzzle Friendly

Tags: hash, collision-resistance

Is there any example of a Hash function that is collision-resistant but may not be puzzle-friendly, similarly example of a hash function that is puzzle-friendly but not collision-resistant?

**Puzzle friendliness**: A hash function $H$ is said to be **puzzle‐friendly** if for every possible $n$‐bit output value $y$, if $k$ is chosen from a distribution with high min‐entropy, then it is infeasible to find $x$ such that $H(k|| x) = y$ in time significantly less than $2^n$ ($k$ and $y$ is given).

Comment: I am thinking of an example in which a Hash function is collision-resistant but not puzzle-friendly, and another example in which function is puzzle-friendly but not collision-resistant.

Comment: Puzzle friendliness. A hash function H is said to be puzzle‐friendly if for every possible n‐bit output value y, if k is chosen from a distribution with high min‐entropy, then it is infeasible to find x such that H(k ‖ x) = y in time significantly less than 2^n.

Comment: I don't see the relation with collision. This is rather finding a suffix to attack.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42042840/properties-of-a-cryptographic-hash-function

It seems to be something from the cryptocurrency community, rather than a common cryptographic definition.

Comment: @SAIPeregrinus the way they tell.

Comment: Does $k$ has a fixed size? And also, the source of the question?

Comment: @kelalaka k is usually a nonce, so any positive integer value.

Comment: But what if $len(k) < 10$ and $len(x) < 10$, who can be protected!

Comment: it didn't get your point.

Comment: If the length of the $k$ and $x$ are small we can search, so there must be some bound like 128-bit and 128-bit etc.

Comment: Consider $SHAx(k||x) = SHA256(k||x) || k||x$ collision resistant but no puzzle-friendly and no pre-image resistance.

Comment: why this is not pre-image resistance?

Comment: After 256 bit output, the rest is there?

Comment: yeah, that makes sense. Is there any example for the other way around?

Comment: Use MD5, no collision resistance anymore, but puzzle‐friendly